# Elite Users query on data.stackexchange is probably written in reverse

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I tried executing the *Elite Users* query on [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/3543/elite-users-those-who-hold-x-of-all-reputation). When I entered 10 in the percent box the resulting number of users was greater than the number of users when I entered 1 in the percent box.

As I understand from the description provided for the query, the number of users must decrease when I increase percentage, but right now it is in reverse.

Is this wrong query execution or I am interpreting it in a wrong way?

Here are the screenshots also

**With 1 percent**

[image: 1 percent results]

**With 10 percent**

[image: With 10 percent results]

Comment: You're interpreting it the wrong way. It shows the top percentage. If you enter 10 percent a large group of users will be part of that group then if you enter 1 percent, that is closer to the top.

Comment: @rene so it is like the percentage that is shown in the profile section like `top x% this week`

Comment: @VivekMishra, yeah, sort of. Note that you can easily fork SEDE queries to make your own version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation in that query is confusing at best.

I have rewritten that [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/545690?percent=1) a bit

```sql
select top 100 rank() over( order by reputation desc) as rnk
     , cast(rank() over( order by reputation desc, creationdate) as decimal) 
       / (select count(*) from users) * 100.0  as [Top % all time]
     , id as [User Link]
     , reputation
     , sum(reputation) over(order by reputation desc) as [running rep sum]
     , ##percent:float##/100.0 * (select sum(reputation) from users) totrep_perc
     , (select sum(reputation) from users) totrep
from users
```

The query takes 1% percent of total reputation and then calculates a running sum of the reputation of users, ordered descending. Take a look at this picture:

[image: running rep 1 percent of total rep]

When you query 0.5% percent, the reputation for the cut-off will be lower, hence you'll reach the running sum of that rep sooner so it will return less users, as shown by this picture:

[image: running rep 0.5 percent]

It could make sense to define the percentage the other way around but I leave that as exercise for the reader.

Comment: This one looks a proper description

Comment: what does last 2 columns denote?

Comment: The last column is sum(reputation) of all users, totrep_perc is sum(reputation) of all users multiplied by given percentage divided by 100. I basically copied that from the original query